# How to set the selected item highlighted in Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

Is there any way to high-light the selected item in alertdialog? In my case I added two items to the alertdialog, and I want to set the clicked item as high-lighted. My current approach is that I can only high-light one item but not user interactive.I think my alertdialog cannot remember selected item.Here is my approach-

```
lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
    val listItems=arrayOf("English", "Thai")
    var selectedElement= 0

    val builder=AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Choose Language")
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems,selectedElement,DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { dialogInterface, i ->
                if (i == 0) {
                setLocale("en")
                recreate()

            }

            if (i == 1) {
                        setLocale("th")
                recreate()

            }
            dialogInterface.dismiss()

    })

    dialog= builder.create()
    dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after getting through a lot of references, finally I came up with a solution by using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). I save values for selected items'position in SharedPreferences and retrieve at the start of the application. By using that way, I am able to see the selected item when I start the application next time. Here is the code I changed to -

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        var selectedItems= -1

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        loadLoacle()
        loadvalue()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

private fun changeLanguage(){
    lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
    val listItems=arrayOf("English", "Thai","Myanmar")
    val builder=AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Choose Language")
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems,selectedItems,DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {dialogInterface,i->
        if (i == 0) {
            setLocale("en")
            recreate()
        }

        if (i == 1) {
            setLocale("th")
            recreate()
        }

        if (i == 2) {
            setLocale("my")
            recreate()
        }
        setvalue(i)
        dialogInterface.dismiss()

    })
    dialog= builder.create()
    dialog.show()

}

private fun setLocale( lang:String) {

    val locale=Locale(lang)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config=Configuration()
    config.locale=locale
    baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)

    var editor=getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putString("My_Lang", lang)
    editor.apply()

}

private fun loadLoacle(){
    var prefs=getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val language:String? = prefs.getString("My_Lang","")
    println("RESULT"+language)
    setLocale(language!!)
}

private fun setvalue( v:Int) {

    var editor=getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putInt("value", v)
    editor.apply()

}

private fun loadvalue(){
    var prefs=getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val language:Int? = prefs.getInt("value",0)
    selectedItems = prefs.getInt("value",0)
    println("RESULT"+language)
    setvalue(language!!)

}
}
```

BTW, Feel free to edit. HAPPY CODING :)